# Invalid json format and how can I return access_key from an iam user?

Tags: python, boto

Im creating an iam user with boto but Im having an error, invalid json format.

But it seems that I have the json variable correctly, do you see where the issue is?

And also do you know after create_access_key(username) do you know how can return the secret access key  to print it?

```
pName = "name"
username = "user"
pJson= {
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
 import boto.iam.connection

 c = boto.iam.connect_to_region("us-east-1")
 c.create_user(username)
 c.put_user_policy(username, pName, pJson)
 c.create_access_key(username)
 k = c.get_all_access_keys(username)
 print k['list_access_keys_response']['list_access_keys_result']['access_key_metadata'][0]['access_key_id']
 # how to return secret access key?
```

Comment: Can you paste the traceback you get?

Answer (score 1):

The policy document ought to be a string according to the [boto documentation](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/iam.html#boto.iam.connection.IAMConnection.put_user_policy); thus you'd use `json.dumps` yourself to convert the dictionary into a string:

```
policy_document = json.dumps(pJson)
c.put_user_policy(usename, pName, policy_document)
```